Cardinalidad y ordinalidad en lucidchart

LucidChart dice que usa la notación pata de gallo. Pero veo que explica una cardinalidad 1 y solo 1 que es usada por ADW que en realidad significa lo mismo que la Uno.
¿Pueden aclararme por qué lucid chart hace esta mezcla?, O es ¿que son 2 cardinalidades diferentes?.
Gracias.

viste esto? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33781451/73749
